# Not able to load a gif when user clicks on a link

Tags: jquery, html, css

css code:-

```
.se-pre-con {
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 9999;
background: url('UrlToTheImage') center no-repeat #fff;
```

jquery code:-

```
$('a').click(function(){
  $(".se-pre-con").show();
}
```

In my html I have many links.So whenever someone clicks on the link I want to display a gif image till the clicked link is  loaded.There is no problem in displaying the gif without jquery i.e. when i just normally display that gif in my html,it gets displayed.But I want to display it only when a link is clicked.Ant btw I am using these two cdn:-

```
<script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.2/modernizr.js"></script>
```

my html code:

```
<a  class="se-pre-con" href="LINKURL" >TEST</a></h4>
```

Comment: Can you show how did you apply the CSS and the actual jquery click event in your html?

Comment: I did't add applied css and jquery to my html.I thought jquery will do it since I am applying to all 'a' i.e. links.

Comment: Your jquery above will show all elements with class="se-pre-con" applied when an anchor is clicked. If you want your image to be displayed once anchor is clicked you need to add class="se-pre-con".

Comment: This will display the link with TEST text if that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the example.

```
<html>

 <body>
   <a href="">Show image</a>
   <img src="..." class="se-pre-con" style="display:none" />
   <script>
    $('a').click(function(){          
      $(".se-pre-con").show();
    }
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: so should I remove image url from css?

Comment: Where did you apply the "se-pre-con" class? Is it in DIV?

Comment: I tried applying class as edited in question area because you said class needs to be applied in comment section.But now I am trying to apply how you have submitted in answer section.

Comment: Please confirm your use case is that you have an image that is currently hidden, when user clicks a link it will show right?

Comment: What I want is when a user clicks on any link on my page I want to display a  loading gif till the clicked link is displayed.

Comment: Apply the "se-pre-con" to the image tag you want to display not to the anchor itself. Please see updated example above.

Comment: I tried what you said but it does not displays my gif image till the page is loaded.Are you sure your code is right?

Comment: Sorry my bad, put the script tag at the bottom before the closing </body> tag. Please see updated code above.

Comment: It is not working, I tried your updated code.Image is not being displayed.

Comment: It is working in my end. One last question, did you add your CSS file where .se-pre-con is located in your html file? Or can you please show your code snippet for html.

Comment: Can you please tell me about your code here on jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=NvpbhflGGi

Comment: please join the session and help me out